# Can we check if object is a key-value type in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I want to check if a object is a key-value type. Is there anywhere to check it?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘a key-value type’? Do you mean a single `Map.Entry`? Or a whole `Map` (or some specific implementation)? Or perhaps something like a `Pair` (that can be used to create a map)? Or some custom class? — Note that the answer will be different in each case. If you're coming from a loosely-typed language, your familiar ideas and patterns won't necessarily translate directly to Kotlin, which is based on inheritance and strong typing; you can't write code to handle _any_ ‘type with keys and values’ if it doesn't extend a relevant type.

Answer (score 0):

Do you means ket-value is map collection? Right?

You can check type using 'is'.

if (tmp is String)
print("this type is string")